# Get the schema name for specific table in SQL/Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get the schema names for below table on Oracle. Could you please help me to understand whether below query is checking for all the schemas or not.

```
select * from all_tables
where table_name like '%ELEC_SURROGATE_KEY';
```

Hoping for some help here.

Thanks!

Comment: Oracle has 3 type of dictionary views. 
user_(...) - "object" owned by the connected user , all_(...) "object" accessible to the user, dba_(...) "object" in DB.  
`all_tables`shows you description of relational tables accessible to the user.

Answer (score 0):

all_tables will show you all tables granted (directly or via role) to the user executing that query.

So, it is possible that there are tables matching `like '%ELEC_SURROGATE_KEY'`, that does not show up in your query.

Answer (score -1):

In SQL:

```
select TABLE_SCHEMA 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE'%YourTableName%'
```